# Repeat 16x full and many fragments. By your obese guy (or thin?)

Tags: riddle, knowledge

```
Always correct
approximately
this instant
the
rhythmic
spirit
sibling

Inspect (split to third)
this thing
this instant
the
rhythmic
spirit
sibling
```

---

*Note: The answer is a phrase. Went through first 10 pages of the tags but couldn't find an apporpriate one.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "obese guy (or thin?)" must be

> [Fatboy Slim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatboy_Slim)

because the wordlist consists of

> synonyms for the lyrics of [The Rockafeller Skank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rockafeller_Skank). In the lyrics, these phrases (and their fragments) are repeated many, many times.

Here's how they match:

> ```
>  Always correct   approximately  this instant
>           Right           about           now
>   the rhythmic spirit sibling
>   The     Funk   Soul Brother
>
>  Inspect (split to third) this thing this instant
>                         Check it out          now
>   the rhythmic spirit sibling
>   The     Funk   Soul Brother
> ```

Comment: You are, of course, correct. Happy holidays!